# Mobile JQuery Advancements

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to apply  date picker and time picker controls in mobile views
. I have tried a lot but everything went in vein. Atlast my  hope  is stack overflow. Please
help me  if somebody has applied Datepickers or time pickers in mobile views  then please tell me the procedure to apply that. Thank You very much 
I have tried one way that is given over here

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/

I am using **Jquery.mobile.1.3**, the latest. I have written this in script and css section

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.css" /> 
<script src="jQuery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.js"></script>
```

and used control in similar way as mentioned but it never worked for me

```
<input type="date" name="date" id="date" value=""  />
```

Comment: What is the question? What is the problem you're having? Any errors etc.

Comment: The ui-datepicker experiment is from 1.0 alpha 4 - it is *very* outdated, and it has not been updated since.  There are a couple of mature options - [jQM-DateBox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/) and [mobiscroll](http://mobiscroll.com/) to name 2 of the bigger projects. The smaller projects generally get listed in the [JQM Resources Page](http://jquerymobile.com/resources/#Plugins).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you even read http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker ?

you need four things:

1) a label
in html

```
<label for="date">Date Input:</label>
```

2) an input field
in html

```
<input type="date" name="date" id="date" value=""  />
```

3) an include of js files
in html

```
<script src="jQuery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.js"></script>
```

4) an altering of standard date behaviour
in script

```
$( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.degradeInputs.date = true;
});
```

regards
zY

Comment: did you post your code partially? if above code is your complete code, you are missing some things. just telling you